# Policy acceptance popup before downloading documents in SharePoint 2013 library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, custom-actions, popup, download

I have a specific requirement, whenever a SharePoint user clicks on a download button for a SharePoint library document, a pop up should get open which will have policies and at bottom of popup there should be two buttons as Accept and do not agree.

On click of "**Accept**" the document should download and on click of "**Do not Agree**" another message should be displayed that "**As you are not agreeing to policies the document cannot be downloaded**"

I am using SharePoint 2013, Also I need to save site as template and create many sites from this template, thus kindly suggest a solution which will be compatible with site template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box this is not possible.

If you are open to custom development then follow below steps

1. Hide existing download button using custom action
2. Hide context menu option to download file using custom action
3. Create new ribbon button. Now you will have complete control over the click event.

Comment: can you please provide more insight for above three action. if you provide code that would be good as i am battling with same issue